# Compile-time equivalent to std::accumulate()

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, gcc4.8

I tried to code a basic, **compile-time** version of [`std::accumulate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) by defining a class template that would recursively iterate through a given range and would add the elements at each iteration.

When compiling a test program using `gcc 4.8.4` on `Ubuntu 14.04`, I get the following error:

```
compile-time-accumulate.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
compile-time-accumulate.cpp:44:40: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::cbegin() const [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >; typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type>::const_pointer = const int*]’
                               v.cbegin(),
                                        ^
compile-time-accumulate.cpp:46:32: error: ‘class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
                               0>::value;
```

Here's the code:

[<kbd>Run it online</kbd>](http://cpp.sh/6k4e)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template
<
    typename     ResultType,
    typename     IteratorType,
    IteratorType Iterator,
    int          RangeLength,
    ResultType   InitialValue
>
struct accumulator
{
    static_assert(RangeLength > 1, "The range length must be > 1");
    static constexpr ResultType value = InitialValue
                                      + accumulator<ResultType,
                                                    IteratorType,
                                                    Iterator + 1,
                                                    RangeLength - 1,
                                                    *Iterator>::value;
};

template
<
    typename     ResultType,
    typename     IteratorType,
    IteratorType Iterator,
    //int          RangeLength,
    ResultType   InitialValue
>
struct accumulator<ResultType, IteratorType, Iterator, 1, InitialValue>
{
    static constexpr ResultType value = InitialValue + *Iterator;
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {4,5,6,7};

    const int a = accumulator<int,
                              decltype(v.cbegin()),
                              v.cbegin(),
                              4,
                              0>::value;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

So basically, the standard doesn't allow the use of variables in template arguments, which is what I'm doing here:

```
const int a = accumulator<int,
                          decltype(v.cbegin()),
                          v.cbegin(),
                          4,
                          0>::value;
```

**Q:** What is the proper method for coding a class template (or any other "compile-time" computation mechanism) for achieving a similar result to `std::accumulate()` ?

(Ideally, one should be able pass custom ranges and binary operations like the real `std::accumulate()`)

**EDIT:** The `std::vector` used in the code is just an example. I've also tried `std::array` and C-style arrays but I still had similar problems.

**EDIT2:** I don't want to use macros.

**EDIT3:** I don't want to use external libraries. The goal here is to do a simple, self-contained **compile-time computation** block. Class template was the my first idea, but I'm open to other suggestions/techniques.

Comment: `std::vector` storage is allocated during runtime. Thus, is not possible to iterate through a `std::vector` during compile time.

Comment: If you used an integer_sequence instead of a vector, I think you could pull this off easier.

Comment: you may iterate over `std::array` as it's size is known at compile time. You cannot do that for `std::vector`

Comment: There's a set of constexpr containers [here](https://github.com/Arcoth/Constainer); [`accumulate`](https://github.com/Arcoth/Constainer/blob/master/Algorithms.hxx#L171) is also provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vector`'s storage is allocated during runtime. Thus, is not possible to iterate through a std::vector during compile time.

Now for `std::array` and raw arrays. Provided that your `std::array` variable is a `constexpr` you could use the following construction to accumulate it:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T compile_time_accumulator(std::array<T, N> const &A, int const i = 0) {
  return (i < N)? A[i] + compile_time_accumulator(A, i + 1) : T(0);
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5b79dcb50537859)

And for raw arrays, provided also that they are declared `constexpr`, the following construction:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T compile_time_accumulator(T const (&A)[N], int const i = 0) {
  return (i < N)? A[i] + compile_time_accumulator(A, i + 1) : T(0);
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aeb950029ee2df8)

Now in C++14 things about `constexpr` are more relaxed and you could do the following:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T compile_time_accumulator(T const (&A)[N]) {
  T sum(T(0));

  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    sum += A[i];
  }

  return sum;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/383409bb1358e6e6)

or

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr T compile_time_accumulator(std::array<T, N> const &A) {
  T sum(T(0));

  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    sum += A[i];
  }

  return sum;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b2f923f53e46e31)

Comment: Interesting, I [extended your example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d900df52f259ce3a) in order to take custom lambdas, which seems to work well. Thanks!

Comment: @865719 Nice but I would suggest use of `std::plus` as `compile_time_accumulator<int, 4>(v, 0, std::plus<int>(), 42)` instead.

Comment: I agree :) On a related note: after reading a little bit more about `constexpr` (at least in C++11), it seems that calling `std::accumulate()` from a `constexpr` function is legal (cf. [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef13ad5eddfacc7c). However, do we have the guarantee that the `constexpr` function's code (i.e. `ct_std_accumulate_std()` in the code example) will be executed at compile time ?

Comment: @865719 sorry to disappoint you but `std::accumulate` is not `constexpr`. Thus, your example is not a compile time evaluation but rather a runtime evaluation.

Comment: @865719 Also `constexpr` lambdas aren't allowed yet. Must be a gcc bug that accepts them. Clang complains about them. I didn't know also I've made a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159200/constexpr-lambas-in-constexpr-functions-and-evaluation-in-compile-time/33159350#33159367).

Comment: You're right. I was [writing this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/507cb7081082a5d0) when I figured it was weird that gcc compiled the `constexpr` function while the `static_assert()` was rejected.

Comment: On a positive note, [as long as the custom operator is `constexpr`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17c7dcc04e0a0999) it seems that we can work around the lambda limitation :)

Comment: in c++14 error: statement not allowed in constexpr function
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    ^

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector`, as any other memory managing container, is, of course, not iterable during compile time. Given the tag C++11, I suggest using `boost.fusion` :)