# GCC constexpr lambdas in constexpr functions and evaluation in compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, constexpr

Code first, we have the following piece of code that is used to accumulate a `constexpr std::array` in compile time:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename O>
constexpr T compile_time_accumulator(const std::array<T, N> const &A, const std::size_t i, const O& op, const T initialValue)
{
  return (i < N)
       ? op(A[i], compile_time_accumulator(A, i + 1, op, initialValue))
       : initialValue;
}
```

and the following code example to test/varify it (i.e., that it evaluates in compile time):

```
constexpr std::array<int, 4> v {{4, 5, 6, 7}};
std::cout << std::integral_constant<int, compile_time_accumulator(v, 42, std::plus<int>())>::value 
          << std::endl;
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f21ef91109add133)

Now if change the operator `std::plus<int>` with a `constexpr` lambda:

```
constexpr auto lambda_plus = [] (int x, int y) { return x + y; };
```

and call it like below:

```
constexpr std::array<int, 4> v {{4, 5, 6, 7}};
std::cout << std::integral_constant<int, compile_time_accumulator(v, 42, lambda_plus)>::value << std::endl;
                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I get an error, that lambda is not `constexpr` :

> call to non-constexpr function ''

Now doing a litle [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32697323/2352671) I discovered that `constexpr` lambdas aren't support yet.

### Q:

Why if `constexpr` lambdas aren't supported, we are allowed to define a `constexpr` lambda in the first place?

Edit:

It seems that clang doesn't accep the [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bccb610676dbb818). So which compiler is right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6420085/4224575

Comment: @NorahAttkins I've included that reference already.

Comment: then you already had the anser (@Columbo is saying the same thing)

Comment: @NorahAttkins Whoops, I just now realized that. Well, looks like a dup for sure.

Comment: @NorahAttkins It's not a dup. I know that `constexpr` lambdas aren't allowed. I'm asking why in the example gcc accepts them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is indeed ill-formed as per [expr.const]/(2.6); lambdas aren't yet allowed in constant expressions, though a [corresponding proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf) is in circulation. GCC is incorrect in accepting `lambda_plus`'s declaration.

Comment: Yeap seems you're right clang complains about them [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bccb610676dbb818).

Answer (score 3):

C++11 allowed a very limited amount definition of a `constexpr` while C++14 has a long list of is not a `constexpr`

> From n4296 (release candidate for C++14) 5.20.2.6
>
> 5.20 Constant expressions [expr.const]
>
> 2 A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the
>   evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9),
>   would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> 2.6) — a lambda-expression (5.1.2);

So the answer is that lambda's are not OK so the compiler must be wrong.

Comment: Yeap seems you're right clang complains about them [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bccb610676dbb818).

Comment: @101010 Hello (again ;) ), you'll notice that [if you compile with `-std=c++11`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a324c1a5a8a2cbb), both gcc and clang don't allow `std::plus()`... Perhaps the _`constexpr`ness_ of `std::plus::operator()` has been added only since `C++14` (I haven't checked the standard but [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/plus/) don't seem to give similar info on that matter)